# ものに in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 思わず、その胸倉に掴みかかるが、彼女の姿をしていたものに触れた途端、それは波間に消える泡のように掻き消えてしまう。

I have no idea whether it is ものに as a whole, or もの by itself followed by に.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is 「もの + に」.

> 「(object) + **に** + 触{ふ}れる」= "to touch (object)"

The sentence thus means:

> "Without thinking, (I) reach out to seize her by the collar, but the moment (I) touched the **thing that took the shape of the woman**, it disappears like the bubbles disappear between the waves."

Japanese is a highly contextual language.  From this sentence alone, one could not tell if the action-taker would be the speaker himself or a third person.

Comment: Aah, that's right : I didn't realize it was this もの, I was certain it was some sort of grammar. I feel bad for asking such a question, haha.